# Removing the smaller value from a list using function min()

Tags: python, min

In short, this is the plan: I want to remove the smallest value from a Python list. My approach to that was creating a new list `trimmed` , which is basically a copy of the original one but with a condition like:

add it to trimmed only if the value is not equal to min(). Like this:

```
lis=[]
trimmed =[]

n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
for i in range(0, n):
    elements = int(input("Type a number: "))
    lis.append(elements) # adding the elements

# "trimmed" appends a new copy of "lis" removing the smaller value

trimmed = [x for i,x in enumerate(lis) if i != min(lis)]

print(trimmed)
```

The problem is, it sometimes seems to build `trimmed` by removing a value in a specific index rather than removing the actual smaller one. E.g. I have just inputted 5 ,2 ,6 and 9. It should ramv removed number two. Instead, it prints out [5, 2, 9]

Comment: well, *of course* because that is what you used in your condition, `i` from `for i,x in enumerate(lis)` which *is the index*.

Comment: In `for i,x in enumerate(lis)`, `i` is the *index* of the element, not the value.  The minimum value was 2, so you're omitting the element at index 2, regardless of its value.

Comment: As an aside, move `min(lis)` **outside the loop**. You've made a linear time algorithm *quadratic time* by putting `min(lis)` inside the list comprehension condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `if i != min(lis)` checks the minimum value against the *index* variable `i` instead of the value itself `x`. `enumerate` gives back `(index, val)` pairs i.e, `(i, x)` here. It happened that `min(lis)` was 2, so whenever `i` hits 2, that value will be trimmed, hence you saw 6 disappearing (which was at 2nd index). Fix is to compare against `x`:

```
trimmed = [x for i,x in enumerate(lis) if x != min(lis)]
```

should do.

But better yet, let us compute the minimum only once (above computes many times):

```
minimum = min(lis)
trimmed = [x for i,x in enumerate(lis) if x != minimum]
```

and further, you don't seem to need `i` at all:

```
minimum = min(lis)
trimmed = [x for x in list if x != minimum]
```

Answer (score 2):

The index doesn't have anything to do with the minimum value. No need to enumerate.

```
minval = min(lis)
trimmed = [x for x in lis if x != minval]
```